# Caches to be used in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, optimization

Using OpCache and Magento Default Cache is enough to reduce resource utilisation for repeated requests on the same content?
Do I need to add any other type of Cache? If yes what?

Answer (score 2):

It's actually possible to have a <0.5s TTFB with all Magento caches OFF.

Caches don't make sites faster, they reduce resource utilisation for repeated requests on the same content, don't confuse the two.

> I have a powerful server so I don't think its a problem with that

Define powerful.

Having lots of RAM or lots of cores won't improve performance. The revision of the CPU, it's clock speed, the L2 cache size, bus speed, memory controller, motherboard chipset, RAM latency and bus speed all have a MASSIVE impact on performance.

> All the settings for Mysql and Php and Apache are done

*All the settings are done?* There are no one size fits all configuration settings, if you have merely copied and pasted configuration files from the internet, then it's extremely likely your server is completely misconfigured.

---

I don't mean to be harsh but there seems to be a common misconception that developers are qualified to be system administrator's. Being able to use a package manager to install applications, or even compiling from source doesn't make you any more of a system administrator than a store owner is a developer,  because they can drop modules in via Magento connect.

Configuring a server properly comes from testing the server specifically for your needs, refining the configuration and repeating tests. Most importantly having a full and detailed understanding of exactly what the effects of what you are changing are. So that you have a fast, reliable, predictable server that you can diagnose and rectify when things go wrong.

It sounds like you would benefit from being with a proper Magento host that specialises in high performance environments, that way you can focus your attention on your store, not learning how to manage a server.

Comment: Caches don't make sites faster, they reduce resource utilisation for repeated requests on the same content, don't confuse the two.
Can you tell what other Caches can I use?

Comment: Trust me I am not trying to be a system administrator i just need to fix my site nothing more nothing less. If i had a system administrator to go to I would and I assumed that this is the place to get answers not be judged!!!!

Comment: This is the place for answers, and if you look at the answers and technical depth I've previously given, you'll see that. But in this case, the answer is that you are out of your depth and you should seek a professional, not try to do it yourself. "How can I set up a server for Magento" is on a par with asking "How can I build a Magento store" - if either are being asked, the answer is to pay a professional to do it. Specialist hosting companies exist for this specific reason.

Comment: 'Caches don't make sites faster, they reduce resource utilisation for repeated requests on the same content'. This is true from the perspective of the server executing lines of code and there being database requests required (neither of which are done any faster with cache), but cache does make a site faster - as far as the user is concerned the response to each request is sent quicker as the server is doing less work, hence it renders more quickly in the browser which.

Comment: `But cache does make a site faster - as far as the user is concerned` - Assuming that the page has been visited before, with the same parameters/conditions, and that the cache entry hasn't expired and that the customer hasn't done anything (largely) unique on the page - they'll be served a cached asset. But if the cache is cold or the user has made their session unique (and thus the cache entry is invalid), then a cache won't improve performance - if anything, the overhead of checking the cache will add to page load time.

Comment: A cache won't make *any* essential part of a Magento store faster; it won't improve load time for registration, for login, for add-to-cart, for cart view, for checkout, for wishlist, for compare. A site MUST be quick to begin with, a cache should NEVER be used to give the illusion of better speed. Sure, drop a cache in when the site is quick - so that the server uses less resources, but *never* use a cache because your site is slow, because it will be equally as slow (and won't sell, will lose SERPs) with a cache - the worst thing will be that you'll think you have fixed it.

Comment: I totally agree, a site must perform well before implementing caching - as I say in nearly all my responses to FPC queries on here, FPC is not a magic bullet.  It is however a valuable tool in further improving the performance of your store.  I only made a note here as it sounded like you were suggesting that FPC is totally redundant in every application - just wanted to add a bit of a fuller picture.  Certainly not meaning to offend, apologies if it came across this way,

Comment: I'm not easily offended :) I just like to draw a line between speed and caching. If people want to improve speed, first improve speed. If people want to reduce hardware utilisation, add a cache.